# Router to router setup via 49 meter long cat-6 cable

Tags: router, wired-networking

once again I am repeating my question,
Reliance ISP--> connected with ADSL Modem-->connected with TPLINK Router (First Router)--->connected with second Router), Straight cable connected first router lan port is not recognizing to my lapotp as it has 49 meter long,

same thing is working brilliant when connected via Patch cord- 2mtr,

router setting is fine, as it works via patch cord

Comment: Please don’t ask the same question twice.

Comment: Why are you repeating it and wasting people's time? It has already been answered. The cable has too much loss on it. Get a better cable, reduce the length or do the wiring properly.

Comment: The same reason as to why you cannot be heard a mile away even if you scream at the top of your lungs. 100 ft is max distance CAT cables will support - translates to 33m

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as per my knowledge cat-6 cable can work up to 100Mtr, and I am using 49 mtrs only, and it is my requirement i.e.49 mtrs

Answer (score 1):

Check the continuity (all 8 conductors, pinout (all 8 conductors), and twisted-pair pairings (all 4 pairs) of your 49m cable. A pinout tester or multimeter/continuity tester won't tell you which pins are paired in a twisted pair, and the right pairings are non-obvious and yet critical:

1&2
3&**6**
**4**&**5**
7&8